# Missing tag "<Header>" for "<AmazonEnvelope>" in Amazon MWS Feeds

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-mws, amazonsellercentral

We're submitting the following feed using the SubmitFeed operation of the Feeds API section.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
  <Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>X</MerchantIdentifier>
  </Header>
  <MessageType>CartonContentsRequest</MessageType>
  <Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <CartonContentsRequest>
      <ShipmentId>X</ShipmentId>
      <NumCartons>X</NumCartons>

  <Carton>
    <CartonId>X-1</CartonId>
    <Item>
      <SKU>X-1</SKU>
      <QuantityShipped>X</QuantityShipped>
      <QuantityInCase>X</QuantityInCase>
    </Item>
  </Carton>
  <Carton>
    <CartonId>X-2</CartonId>
    <Item>
      <SKU>X-1</SKU>
      <QuantityShipped>X</QuantityShipped>
      <QuantityInCase>X</QuantityInCase>
    </Item>
  </Carton>
  <Carton>
    <CartonId>X-3</CartonId>
    <Item>
      <SKU>X</SKU>
      <QuantityShipped>X</QuantityShipped>
      <QuantityInCase>X/QuantityInCase>
    </Item>
  </Carton>
  </CartonContentsRequest>
  </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

and get success submitting. But then when we call GetFeedSubmissionResult we get this error:

```
<Result>
  <MessageID>100001</MessageID>
  <ResultCode>Error</ResultCode>
  <ResultMessageCode>1</ResultMessageCode>
  <ResultDescription>Missing tag "<Header>" for "<AmazonEnvelope>". (FBA_INBOUND_CARTON_003)</ResultDescription>
  <AdditionalInfo>
    <SKU>-</SKU>
  </AdditionalInfo>
</Result>
```

I've tried everything with no success and we're clearly sending the tag Header in the Amazon Envelope.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed. It turns out I was sending a line break as the first character of the XML, breaking it all.